# Tor anonymous proxy Spyware

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, malware

I found a link to "WindowsTechies" help and support center :

http://windowstechies.com/-/en/spyware/?t=1&k=tor%20anonymous%20proxy&m=b&u=&c=53624071110&gclid=CL-e44rwscMCFWjItAodcF0A6A

about a Spyware introduced by Tor proxy !?

And, "they" propose a download to get ride of it!

Is there anyone heard about this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This so-called "Tor Proxy" is not affiliated with the Tor project, the the Tor Browser, nor the Tor network. It is just a malicious software that uses the name of a well-known product to deceive users into downloading it and then running it. To protect yourself against such threats, use you favourite anti-spyware. But the main precaution is to download Tor/TorBrowserBundle only from https://torproject.org, and to verify the GPG signatures of the files after downloading. Same would apply if you are using a Linux distribution that bases its connection to the internet around Tor: download only from the original source, use HTTPS, and verify GPG signatures.